# Use PortDuffXferMode on view without alpha?

Tags: android, android-graphics

I have a custom view where I want the views below it to show in some parts. I'm doing this with `paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));` after drawing the area that I want to display on during `onDraw`.

Unfortunately, this only seems to work if the alpha of the view is not 1, 0.99, for example, works correctly. This is probably because PorterDuff modes are alpha blending modes, and if alpha is 1, there's no alpha blending.

Is there a way to force it to work, even with an alpha of 1 though?

Comment: post images with the expecting result and what you got now

Comment: @pskink, it's essentially the same as trying to make an image view with rounded corners, and the corners end up being rounded, but the background is black instead of transparent.